# Report Manager: Passing parameter via url

Tags: reporting-services, reportmanager

I'm trying to pass a parameter serial_number to the SQL Server Report Manager and generate a report called "Report_Top_Level". I've looked at several examples of this as and as far as I can tell this should work.

```
http://Server_Name/Reports_SQLSERVER/Pages/Report.aspxItemPath=/Report_Top_Level&serial_number=22
```

However, while its generating the report screen the parameter serial_no is not being entered and must be done manually by the user.

There is a second parameter in the report but it is dependent on the serial_no value and hidden. Could this be the cause of the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also same kind of report where the second parameter depends on first parameter and is hidden. I tried in the below way and it worked. Try this - 
`http://Server_Name/Reportserver?/<foldersifanywherethereportis>/Report_Top_Level&serial_number=22`

Comment: I did not realise there was a difference between Report_Server and Reports for the purpose of the URL. Using
'http://Server_Name/Report_Server_SQLSERVER/Pages/Report.aspxItemPath=/Report_Top_Level&serial_number=22' worked